# Study frequency of occurrence of alternatives in a test

Tags: list-manipulation, probability-or-statistics

There is a test with 5 alternatives A, B, C, D, E, I need to study the frequency of occurrence of these alternatives in a test of 80 questions, "n" times
I can not think of a way to program it, help me please

**EDIT**
I will try to explain this better. A teacher builds a test of 80 questions with 5 alternatives A, B, C, D, E which are randomly distributed by the person who built the test, we imagine that this person builds a very large number of tests and follows the same logic of constructing 80 questions with 5 random alternatives,
I want to know the frequency of the alternatives A, B, C, D, E in the construction of a large number of tests, I want to know if there is any trend of the alternatives, as the test must be constructed many times let's say n = 1000000, here is where Mathematica enters

**EDIT 2**
*An idea, a test of 80 questions is constructed, with 5 random alternatives each of the 80 questions, then another and another over the years, is it possible that within that large number of tests, there is an alternative A, B , C, D, E that is more likely than other*

Comment: `Counts[data]/80`?

Comment: .. or `PDF[MultinomialDistribution[80, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}/5], {a, b, c, d, e}]`?

Comment: thanks for answering, could you explain a bit the code, I can not get it to work
Maybe with an example

Comment: An appropriate test depends on how you sampled.  From what population did you select respondents?  Did each respondent answer 80 questions?  As far as I can tell this question is still unclear, doesn't directly involve *Mathematica*,  and should be asked (with the sampling details) at https://stats.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: First, I really don't think that someone needs to know all of the statistical jargon to ask a good question.  However, I don't see that both of your edits has added much clarity.  Are there 5 different tests each with 80 questions? Are there a common set of 80 questions with one additional question selected from A, B, C, D, or E?   Or is each question a multiple choice with 5 possible answers?  You also mention "trend".  Does that mean that the frequencies might be ranked A < B < C < D < E?  Or does trend mean a change over time (and you've not mentioned anything about "time").

Comment: @JimB , hi , see, EDIT 2

Answer (score 1):

Under the not-too-implausible assumptions

(1) that the vector `{na, nb, nc, nd, ne}` (where `na+nb+nc+nd+ne == 80`) corresponding to the number of correct answers that are `"A"`, `"B"`, ...`"E"` in a test with 80 questions is a random variable with distribution  `dist = MultinomialDistribution[80, {pa,pb,pc,pd,pe}]` for some vector `{p1,p2,p3,p4,p5}` such that `pa+pb+pc+pd+pe == 1`, and

(2) that we have a data set, `data`,  of `n = 500`  5-tuples (500 independent observations from `dist`),

we can

(a) estimate the unknown parameters using [`FindDistributionParameters`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindDistributionParameters.html)

(b) use [`DistributionFitTest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DistributionFitTest.html) to test hypothesis that no letter is favored as the correct answer, that is, we have `pa == pb == pc == pd == pe == 1/5`.

**Examples:**

```
SeedRandom[1]
dist1 = MultinomialDistribution[80, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}/5];
data1 = RandomVariate[dist1, 500];

BarChart[Mean[data1]/80, ChartLabels -> CharacterRange["A", "E"]]
```

[image]

```
FindDistributionParameters[data1, MultinomialDistribution[80, {pa, pb, pc, pd, pe}]]
```

> {pa -> 0.2006, pb -> 0.19805, pc -> 0.201625, pd -> 0.1996, 
>    pe -> 0.200125}

```
DistributionFitTest[data1, 
   MultinomialDistribution[80, {pa, pb, pc, pd, pe}],"HypothesisTestData"][
  "FittedDistributionParameters", {"TestDataTable", All}, "TestConclusion"] // 
  Column // TeXForm
```

> $\begin{array}{l}
>  \{\text{pa}\to 0.2006,\text{pb}\to 0.19805,\text{pc}\to 0.201625,\text{pd}\to 0.1996,\text{pe}\to 0.200125\} \\
>  \begin{array}{l|ll}
>  \text{} & \text{Statistic} & \text{P-Value} \\
> \hline
>  \text{Pearson }\chi ^2 & 2.73603 & 0.638668 \\
> \end{array}
>  \\
>  \text{The null hypothesis that }\text{the data is distributed according to the
>    }\\ \, \, \, \,\text{MultinomialDistribution}[80,\{\text{pa},\text{pb},\text{pc},\text{pd},\text{pe}\}] \text{is not rejected at the }\\ \, \, \, \,5\text{
>    percent level }\text{based on the }\text{Pearson }\chi ^2\text{ test.} \\
> \end{array}$

```
DistributionFitTest[data1, MultinomialDistribution[80, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}/5], 
  "HypothesisTestData"][{"TestDataTable", All}, "TestConclusion"] // 
 Column // TeXForm
```

> $\begin{array}{l}
>  \begin{array}{l|ll}
>  \text{} & \text{Statistic} & \text{P-Value} \\
> \hline
>  \text{Pearson }\chi ^2 & 2.7436 & 0.642936 \\
> \end{array}
>  \\
>  \text{The null hypothesis that }\text{the data is distributed according to the
>    }\\ \, \, \, \, \text{MultinomialDistribution}\left[80,\left\{\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{5}\right\}\right] \text{is
>    not rejected at the }\\ \, \, \, \, 5\ \text{ percent level }\text{based on the }\text{Pearson }\chi ^2\text{ test.} \\
> \end{array}$

```
SeedRandom[1]
dist2 = MultinomialDistribution[80, {6, 1, 1, 1, 1}/10];
data2 = RandomVariate[dist2, 500];
BarChart[Mean[data2]/80, ChartLabels -> CharacterRange["A", "E"]]
```

[image]

```
FindDistributionParameters[data2, MultinomialDistribution[80, {pa, pb, pc, pd, pe}]]
```

> {pa -> 0.6016, pb -> 0.1027, pc -> 0.098425, pd -> 0.09825, 
>        pe -> 0.099025}

```
DistributionFitTest[data2, MultinomialDistribution[80, {pa, pb, pc, pd, pe}], 
    "HypothesisTestData"]["FittedDistributionParameters", {"TestDataTable", All}, 
   "TestConclusion"] // Column // TeXForm
```

> $\begin{array}{l}
>  \{\text{pa}\to 0.6016,\text{pb}\to 0.1027,\text{pc}\to 0.098425,\text{pd}\to 0.09825,\text{pe}\to 0.099025\} \\
> \begin{array}{l|ll}
>  \text{} & \text{Statistic} & \text{P-Value} \\
> \hline
>  \text{Pearson }\chi ^2 & 2.76649 & 0.655743 \\
> \end{array}
>  \\
>  \text{The null hypothesis that }\text{the data is distributed according to the
>    }\\ \, \, \,\, \text{MultinomialDistribution}[80,\{\text{pa},\text{pb},\text{pc},\text{pd},\text{pe}\}] 
>    \text{is not rejected at the }\\ \, \, \,\,5\text{
>    percent level }\text{based on the }\text{Pearson }\chi ^2\text{ test.} \\
> \end{array}$

```
DistributionFitTest[data2, MultinomialDistribution[80, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}/5], 
   "HypothesisTestData"][{"TestDataTable", All}, "TestConclusion"] // Column
```

> [image]

Comment: When you use `{pa, pb, pc, pd, pe}` in `DistributionFitTest` and none of those values have been defined, then what is being tested is if the data comes from *some* multinomial distribution.  If you wanted to test for equality of the proportions, then you would need to use `{1, 1, 1, 1, 1}/5`.

Comment: @JimB, you are right.  I tested both for `data1`; I forgot to copy/paste second test  for `data2`. Thank you.